# Can you use past continuous tense when the sentence begins with "as"?

Tags: sentence-construction

I have a question whether you can use past continuous tense in a certain sentence.

When you are describing the wind that was blowing when you left home, can you say this?

> As I left home, the wind was blowing hard.

I wasn't sure if you can use past continuous tense in the main clause when the dependent clause begins with "as." So I looked in the dictionaries and couldn't find any sentences like that. Should the sentence be written like this instead?

> As I left home, the wind blew hard.

Comment: It depends entirely what you ***mean***. In , say, *As he left, the clock **was striking** twelve*, the implication is at least *some* peals had already been struck at the moment he left. But *As he left, the clock **struck** twelve* implies the *first* peal rang out at the same time as (or immediately after) he started to leave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use continuous tenses to describe things that are happening before, during and after a point in time. **as** describes such a point in time, so it is OK to use past continuous:

> As I left home, the wind was blowing hard.

This indicates that the wind was blowing before you left home, at the time you left home, and afterward.

> As I left home, the wind blew hard.

The simple past version would indicate that the wind blew briefly at the exact moment that you left home.